# Oracle SQL Dev, "many to many" or "any to any" selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.

I have a table t_one with values(date format mm/dd/yy)

| item | list_val | date_1 | date_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i-12 | "1 , 3 , 5 , 6" | 07/01/22 | 08/28/22 | spaghetti |
| i-15 | "2 , 3 , 4 , 8" | 05/01/22 | 06/30/22 | rigatoni |
| i-17 | "2 , 5" | 05/05/22 | 06/06/22 | farfalle |
| i-19 | "1 , 4 , 9" | 03/01/22 | 08/31/22 | penne |
| i-20 | "8" | 08/01/22 | 12/31/22 | gnocchi |

I have a table t_two with a list of values

| item | date_1 | date_2 | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/06/22 | 08/11/22 | pomodoro |
| 3 | 04/01/22 | 07/31/22 | peperoni |
| 8 | 08/01/22 | 10/10/22 | oliva |
| 9 | 07/01/22 | 10/31/22 | aglio |

What I want to do is to select **t_one** elements according to a given date (is given_date between **date_1** and **date_2**) and if any of the values in the **list_val** is part of the table **t_two** ?

In the case above, for a given_date 08/08/22, the result would be :

- i-12 and 1 (spaghetti pomodoro)
- i-19 and 1 (penne pomodoro)
- i-19 and 9 (penne aglio)
- i-20 and 8 (gnocchi oliva)

It is a kind of search "many to many" or precisely "any to any" with many arguments on both sides.
I thought to solve it with a "for each" in the where-clause but I failed.
I tried to use "intersect" but I didn’t succeed.

Thanks for your help !

SBB

Answer (score 1):

Storing relationships in a delimited list in a string column is bad practice; instead you should use a third table as a bridging table which can contain many-to-one relationships to both `t_one` and `t_two` (and define the referential constraints between the tables to ensure the data is always consistent).

```sql
CREATE TABLE t_bridge (
  item1 CONSTRAINT t_bridge__item1__fk REFERENCES t_one (item),
  item2 CONSTRAINT t_bridge__item2__fk REFERENCES t_two (item)
);
```

Additionally, use a `DATE` column for dates; never store them as a formatted string.

If you must store the connection as a delimited list (please don't) and want rows where the `t_two` dates are entirely between the `t_one` dates then you can use:

```sql
SELECT t1.item AS item1,
       t2.item AS item2,
       t1.value AS value1,
       t2.value AS value2
FROM   t_one t1
       INNER JOIN t_two t2
       ON (   ' , ' || t1.list_val || ' , ' LIKE '% , ' || t2.item || ' , %'
          AND t1.date_1 <= t2.date_1
          AND t2.date_2 <= t1.date_2 )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t_one (item PRIMARY KEY, list_val, date_1, date_2, value) AS
SELECT 'i-12', '1 , 3 , 5 , 6', DATE '2022-07-01', DATE '2022-08-28', 'spaghetti' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'i-15', '2 , 3 , 4 , 8', DATE '2022-05-01', DATE '2022-06-30', 'rigatoni' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'i-17', '2 , 5',         DATE '2022-05-05', DATE '2022-06-06', 'farfalle' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'i-19', '1 , 4 , 9',     DATE '2022-03-01', DATE '2022-08-31', 'penne' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'i-20', '8',             DATE '2022-08-01', DATE '2022-12-31', 'gnocchi' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t_two (item PRIMARY KEY, date_1, date_2, value) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2022-06-06', DATE '2022-08-11', 'pomodoro' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2022-04-01', DATE '2022-07-31', 'peperoni' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, DATE '2022-08-01', DATE '2022-10-10', 'oliva' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, DATE '2022-07-01', DATE '2022-10-31', 'aglio' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ITEM1 | ITEM2 | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i-20 | 8 | gnocchi | oliva |
| i-19 | 1 | penne | pomodoro |

If you want the rows where any part of the date range overlaps then:

```
SELECT t1.item AS item1,
       t2.item AS item2,
       t1.value AS value1,
       t2.value AS value2
FROM   t_one t1
       INNER JOIN t_two t2
       ON (   ' , ' || t1.list_val || ' , ' LIKE '% , ' || t2.item || ' , %'
          AND t2.date_1 <= t1.date_2
          AND t1.date_1 <= t2.date_2 )
```

Which outputs:

| ITEM1 | ITEM2 | VALUE1 | VALUE2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i-15 | 3 | rigatoni | peperoni |
| i-12 | 3 | spaghetti | peperoni |
| i-12 | 1 | spaghetti | pomodoro |
| i-19 | 1 | penne | pomodoro |
| i-19 | 9 | penne | aglio |
| i-20 | 8 | gnocchi | oliva |

---

With a bridging table, the first query would be:

```sql
SELECT t1.item AS item1,
       t2.item AS item2,
       t1.value AS value1,
       t2.value AS value2
FROM   t_one t1
       INNER JOIN t_bridge b
       ON (t1.item = b.item1)
       INNER JOIN t_two t2
       ON (   b.item2 = t2.item
          AND t1.date_1 <= t2.date_1
          AND t2.date_2 <= t1.date_2 )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7RxjQmWO)

Comment: @EsBeeBee If the tables already exist then just `SELECT` from the existing tables and join them using `LIKE` as described in the answer. We do not have access to your system so you are going to have to test the answer there; for the rest of us we need to create some test data to try to replicate the pre-existing setup on your database so we need to create the sample tables/data.